# how to customize Tracking Ecommerce Transactions with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

In the Ecommerce Transactions with Google Analytics, we can code as below:

```
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',       // order ID
    'SitePoint',  // store
    '19.99',      // total
    '1.50',       // tax
    '3.00',       // shipping
    'Chicago',    // city
    'Illinois',   // state
    'USA'         // country
]);
```

But I want to implement it for employer registration page where I wont get order_id and total fields. Instead can I use employer_id and company name by replacing oerder_id and store... 
Will it works ?

for reference you can see [GA Ecommerce](http://www.sitepoint.com/track-ecommerce-transactions-google-analytics-reports/)
How to use it for employer registration ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but it may not be the best way to do it. If I were going to do it this way I'd use some code to generate a dummy transaction id and then set the total fields to $1. Here is some code to generate an order_id:

```
function generateOrderId() {
    // really crude unique ID
    var d = new Date();
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    return d.valueOf()+''+r;
}
```

A better way to do this is to track it with events. These are designed for tracking special things that don't have a dollar amount directly associated. For example, downloads, or the number of times a person clicks play on a video player.

The docs are pretty good and if you understand that Sitepoint article the event tracking won't be hard. (it's actually a simpler process than ecommerce)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide